# I am trying to upload a file from OneDrive to Sharepoint Online (Office 365) while retaining the file's format

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business, power-automate, microsoft-forms

I am using Microsoft Forms to collect a PDF file from the user answering the form. It is to my understanding that the file will be automatically uploaded into my OneDrive for Business storage. I wish to create a backup of that file in my company's SharePoint Online. Is there any way that I can upload the file to SharePoint ?

Currently I am using a Power Automate Flow which is triggered when a file is created in OneDrive. However, upon testing I find that the flow does not always run and sometimes gets stuck. Only when I submit another response on forms with a different uploaded file, then the flow creates both the files at one go.

Below is the current Flow that I am using. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong or if there are ways for me to improve my Flow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a brilliant video online which solves the problem. Anyone who is facing a similar problem can use this video for guidance and help.

Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDW3ikTHu9U